# Find the correlation Corr[X,Y] from the joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, covariance, correlation

The joint pdf is as follows:

$f(x,y) = 5040x^3y^5$  ($0≤x, 0≤y, x+y≤1$)

I have worked out:
$f_{X}(x)=840x^3(1-x)^6$ for ($0≤x≤1$)
$f_{Y}(y)=1260(1-y)^4y^5$ for ($0≤y≤1$)

However, when working out E(X), E(Y) and E(XY) I am unsure what limits to use which is making me get an answer of $\cfrac{17400}{121}$ for the covariance and hence, a massively wrong answer for the correlation.

Can anyone help? It would be massively appreciated

Comment: For $\mathbb{E}[X]$ you integrate $x f_X(x)$ from $0$ to $1$ and similarly for $\mathbb{E}[Y]$. For $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ integrate $xy f(x,y)$ with $y$ from $0$ to $1-x$ and $x$ from $0$ to $1$. You should get $\mathbb{E}[X] = \dfrac{4}{11}$, $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \dfrac{6}{11}$ and $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \dfrac{2}{11}$. This should give covariance to be $-\dfrac{2}{121}$. (I hope my calculations are correct)

Comment: Yes thank you so much! I think I got the values for E[X] and E[Y] somewhere down the line. How did you choose the limits when working out E[XY]? Why did you not use 1-y as a limit as well?

Comment: To compute $\mathbb{E}[g(x,y)]$ for a function $g$, the fundamental formula is  $\mathbb{E}[g(x,y)] = \int_{D} g(x,y) f(x,y) dy dx$ where $D$ is the domain. The domain can be characterised by setting limits for $y$ from $0$ to $1-x$ and for $x$ from $0$ to $1$. So for $\mathbb{E}[X]$, $g(x,y) = x$ and $\mathbb{E}[XY]$, $g(x,y) = xy$. In the first case, you already integrated over $y$ to get $f_X(x)$ and hence you need to integrate over $x$ from $0$ to $1$. Hope that clears the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the support of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the triangle with vertices $$(0,0), (1,0), (0,1).$$  For a given $x \in [0,1]$, the values of $y$ range over $[0, 1-x]$.

It is instructive to consider the general case

$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E}[X^k Y^m] &= \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{1-x} x^k y^m \cdot 5040 x^3 y^5 \, dy \, dx \\
&= 5040 \int_{x=0}^1 x^{3+k} \int_{y=0}^{1-x} y^{5+m} \, dy \, dx \\
&= 5040 \int_{x=0}^1 x^{3+k} \left[\frac{y^{6+m}}{6+m}\right]_{y=0}^{1-x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{5040}{6+m} \int_{x=0}^1 x^{3+k} (1-x)^{6+m} \, dx \\
&= \frac{5040}{6+m} \frac{\Gamma(4+k)\Gamma(7+m)}{\Gamma(11+k+m)} \\
&= \frac{7! (k+3)!(m+5)!}{(k+m+10)!},
\end{align*}$$
where I have used the beta integral identity (as found in the density of a beta distribution)
$$\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)} \int_{x=0}^1 x^{a-1} (1-x)^{b-1} \, dx = 1.$$
From this, we are able to immediately compute all relevant moments through appropriate selection of $k$, $m$:

$$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \frac{7!4!6!}{12!} = \frac{2}{11} \\
\operatorname{E}[X] = \frac{7!4!5!}{11!} = \frac{4}{11} \\
\operatorname{E}[Y] = \frac{7!3!6!}{11!} = \frac{6}{11} \\
\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \frac{7!5!5!}{12!} = \frac{5}{33} \\
\operatorname{E}[Y^2] = \frac{7!3!7!}{12!} = \frac{7}{22}.
$$
The remainder of the calculation I leave as a straightforward exercise.

---

Note that this method of solution works because the joint PDF is of the form $C x^p y^q$ for suitable $C, p, q$, and is readily amenable to such an approach.  We would not perform such a generalization in cases where the resulting integrand would become needlessly complicated.